# Creating a data set using an API with Python

Tags: python, api, dataset

I'm trying to create a  5 years weather data set retrieved from an API

```
city=input("enter\n")
ask=input("enter date\n")
date_format = "%Y-%m-%d"
date_time = datetime.strptime(ask, date_format)

print(date_time)
json_data = requests.get(
    'http://api.worldweatheronline.com/premium/v1/past-weather.ashx',
    params=dict(
        key='my key',
        q=city,
        format='json',
        date=ask,
        tp='24'
    )
).json()
print(json_data)
```

it show 0ne day data.
but i need to collect 5 years data from Api  so i use

```
channels = ['maxtempC','maxtempF', 'mintempC','mintempF']

channels_list = []

for channel in channels:
    JSONContent = requests.get("http://api.worldweatheronline.com/premium/v1/past-weather.ashx" + channel).json()
    channels_list.append([JSONContent['Type'], JSONContent['Temp'], JSONContent['mintem'],JSONContent['views']])

dataset = pd.DataFrame(channels_list)
dataset.sample(5)
```

it gives

```
JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

How i collect 5 years data from Api?

Comment: It seems your question includes your API key. I've edited it but it will remain in the history; it can be removed if you delete your question.

Comment: In your second snippet you're appending the values to the URL which I'm sure is not valid. Instead you should have your data in the query string (`params=`) if it is a GET request or in the body (`data=`) if it is a POST request.

Comment: Temperature, humidity and wind speed

Comment: when i use Get request it give one day data and i need 5 years

Comment: If the `tp` parameter means time period maybe you could increase it to request more data.

Answer (score 3):

without knowing the internals of the API, i can suggest performing a daily call for each day in the 5 years, and appending the daily data to a list:

```
import datetime
import requests
```

defining a function that will return a generator (not a list) for all the days between a given start_date and end_date, which must be inputted as datetime objects:

```
def daterange(start_date, end_date):
    for n in range(int ((end_date - start_date).days)):
        yield start_date + datetime.timedelta(n)
```

example values:

```
city="London"
start_date="2019-03-01"
end_date="2019-03-11"
date_format = "%Y-%m-%d"

start_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(start_date, date_format)
end_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(end_date, date_format)
```

collect daily data from start_date to end_date, one request per day:

```
all_data = []
maxtempC_list = []
maxtempF_list = []
mintempC_list = []
mintempF_list = []


for each_date in daterange(start_date, end_date):
    print(each_date.date())

    ask = str(each_date.date())


    json_data = requests.get(
        'http://api.worldweatheronline.com/premium/v1/past-weather.ashx',
        params=dict(
            key='YOUR_API_KEY',
            q=city,
            format='json',
            date=ask,
            tp='24'
        )
    ).json()
    print(json_data)

    all_data.append(json_data)
    maxtempC_list.append(json_data['data']['weather'][0]['maxtempC'])
    maxtempF_list.append(json_data['data']['weather'][0]['maxtempF'])
    mintempC_list.append(json_data['data']['weather'][0]['mintempC'])
    mintempF_list.append(json_data['data']['weather'][0]['mintempF'])
```

Comment: it work and give 5 years data but if i select limited column then what should i use ?

Comment: i edited in collection for the 4 values you are looking for - you extract them using jsonpath syntax, and append to individual lists. PS: you have reached API call limit, you may want to look for an alternative method or datasource as 5 years of data will cost atleast 1825 API calls. alternatively, upgrade your API account

Comment: it not upgrade. how i save 5 years data in .json file and then convert it into csv??

Comment: i copied the output and save in text file with .json it give error of JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 5 - line 3672 column 1071 (char 4 - 19523

Comment: if you want to save to csv, you need the json module: `import json; json.dumps(all_data)` as you copied the output in dictionary form, not json. or, i could suggest converting to a pandas dataframe and saving that to_csv